# Django динамические поля <select>/<option> в форме

Tags: django, forms

Есть модель так называемых "карточек"

```
class Card(models.Model):
    infinite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=128, default="eBANKING SYSTEM")
    description = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=False)
    balance = models.BigIntegerField(blank=False, default=0)
    owner = models.ForeignKey('users.Profile', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='card_owner')
```

Их, у пользователя может быть сколь угодно. Мне необходимо, чтобы был `<select>` тэг со списком всех "карточек" пользователя, есть, допустим, у него 4 карточки, значит с помощью `<select>` и `<option>` вывести все 4 в форме, чтобы я в дальнейшем мог делать переводы с карточки на карточку. Надеюсь понятно объяснил)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как насчет добавить форму на страницу через `django.forms`?

Пример (forms.py):

```py
from django import forms
from .models import Card

class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    cards = froms.ModelChoiceField(label="", queryset=Card.objects.all(), empty_label="Cards")
    # добавить сюда все, что хотите иметь в форме.
```

Во views.py

```py
from .forms import CreateForm

def view_example(request):
    # добавить логику для if request.method == "POST":....
    form = CreateForm()
    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, "any.html", context)
```

ну и в `any.html`:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <p> {{ form.cards }}</p><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Push me">
</form>
```

код написан на коленке и отражает только идею. При формировании select'a вам необоходимы данные для queryset, а значить при создании объекта формы во `views.py` необходимо определять для кого карты вы хотите

Comment: Я через django.forms и делаю. Сколько сайтов с документациями посмотрел, ни разу не видел поле ModelChoiceField. Огромное Вам спасибо. Хорошего дня, успехов!

Comment: Пожалуйста, документация [здесь](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/fields/)